# I can't import qgis.core in a Python script and I don't know how to change the environment

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to start using Python with QGIS but I cannot get Python to work right. When I try `import qgis.code` in the python shell, I get this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
> import qgis.core
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'

Then I go into Terminal and try this:
`export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python`
But my error message stays the same. Interestingly, if I try running python from Terminal and try to import qgis again, I get a different error code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/qgis/core/__init__.py", line 25, in 
> from qgis._core import *
> ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/qgis/_core.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/qgis_core.framework/Versions/3.18/qgis_core
> Referenced from: /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/Resources/python/qgis/_core.so
> Reason: image not found

I have two versions of Python on my computer (Mac) which has caused so many problems for me; could that be the problem? How do I fix this? I tried following this: [QGIS - ModuleNotFoundError](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361170/qgis-modulenotfounderror?newreg=6f117231efce43d39fae0c49148ac292) but I don't know where to go from there. I am a programming noob so I don't even know what to fix there.

Comment: I ran in a similar issue, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218951/how-to-set-up-qgis-python-environment-properly) suggests that it is difficult. Also, the [Qgis documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts) is quite complex. So far, I have always used python scripts from *within* Qgis, which works, but outside I haven't figured it out yet. For different Python versions, I'd suggest [Conda](https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2019/05/29/using-qgis-from-conda/). Good luck!